# How to update UI when an alarm broadcast receiver receive the event?

Tags: android

In my application there's a main activity which might be show on the top or in the background, and there's a broast receiver who receive the alarm event.

My main activity and the receiver seems to be two instances, and I can't call a static member in main activity (e.g.listview) to update itself from the receiver. It this correct?

So, how do i notify my current main activity to update itself?

p.s. I don't want to show my main activity if it's not currently on top.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One mechanism I have seen used to provide a good solution is a Broadcast Receiver.  You can read more about the solution in the [Common Tasks](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#broadcastreceivers) area of the android documentation.

*Edit:* Although, rereading your question, I'm not positive I have enough information.  If your receiver is already in your activity, then you just need to use the runOnUi(Runnable) call from the Activity to allow you to update the UI.

Comment: I think you're right use another broadcast receiver for updating UI is what i need, thanks.